# Python sipsimple accept method not working in incoming session

Tags: python-3.x, sip

As of documented [here](http://old.sipsimpleclient.org/projects/sipsimpleclient/wiki/SipMiddlewareApi#Session) the `accept()` method can call to accepting the incoming session after a `SIPSessionNewIncoming` notification is sent. I receive the notification but the `accept()` method is not working.

Here is my code:

```
def _NH_SIPSessionNewIncoming (self, notification):
        print("Incoming Call") # It is printing
        session = notification.sender
        session.accept([AudioStream()])
```

It is return nothing. Even not accepting the incoming session.

But the following code returns `cannot call accept in None state`

```
def _NH_SIPSessionNewIncoming (self, notification):
        print("Incoming Call") # It is printing
        self.session.accept([AudioStream()])
```

What will be actual implantation?
Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution. Here is the working code:

```
def _NH_SIPSessionNewIncoming (self, notification):
        print("Incoming Call") # It is printing
        session = notification.sender
        session.accept(session.proposed_streams)
```

Thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).